# How do I print text in same line?

Tags: c#, text, printing

I am new to C#. While displaying text, C# prints every piece of text in a new line. But, I would like have all the pieces in the same line like `Four Hundred Fifty Eight`; kindly refer to the image below.
What should I do ?
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of Console.WriteLine(), use Console.Write().

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using `Console.WriteLine()`, all you need to do is use `Console.Write()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Console.Write() instead of Console.WriteLine()

Answer (score 0):

You could terminate the string forcibly, like this

```
Debug.Print("{0:X} \0", byteReceived[0]);
```

Then new .Print after that would be in the same line.

Comment: Hi, I like Your answer and thinking about it, however `Debug` should not be used for the standard output - it is more a feature used for finding issues in code. Does it work also with `Console` methods?

Comment: It doesn't work for Console.WriteLine(). For Console you could look at Jeff Zarnett's answer.

Comment: Thinkgs like that is always better mention directly in question to provide full info =) just FYI